# vba function 2 parameter 1 return not working

Tags: vba, excel

I want to have a function, where i can insert 2 Integers and it Returns me one Integer as a result

```
Sub test()
Dim x As Integer
x = getConst 1, 0 ' here is where i get the error message
MsgBox "Vakue" & x
End Sub

Function getConst(ry As Integer, rx As Integer) As Integer
getConst = 3 'actually that one: getConst = 34 * ry * ry - 30 * ry + 8.5 * rx * rx + 7.5 * rx, but that should make any difference
End Function
```

Im used to Java coding, and it should work somewhat like that, but it says "Erwartet: Anweisungsende" so in english ~"Expectet end of clause"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieving a value from functions requires parentheses

```
x = getConst(1, 0)
```

but when you call them as a procedure (without retrieving the return value) then you can forget the paraenthesis:

```
getConst 1, 0
```

Comment: ok this works, but how comes that brackets are allowed in this case, while they cause an error when u have 2 Parameters in so many other cases?

Comment: assignments using function calls require `()` around the arguments, the called routines must be `Function xxx()`, procedure calls don't have `()` around arguments and the called routine must be a `Sub xxx()`

Answer (score 0):

The single problem you have is the missing brackets around the function call in `Sub Test()` ... i.e.

```
x = getConst(1, 0)
```

You should rethink the use of Integer variables when in your actual function you multiply by decimals.

```
Sub test()
Dim x As Integer

    x = getConst(1, 0)
    MsgBox "Value " & x

End Sub

Function getConst(ry As Integer, rx As Integer) As Integer
' getConst = 3 'actually that one:
' getConst = 34 * ry * ry - 30 * ry + 8.5 * rx * rx + 7.5 * rx 
' but that should make any difference

    getConst = 34 * ry ^ 2 - 30 * ry + 8.5 * rx ^ 2 + 7.5 * rx

End Function
```